# workflow to update issue state in target project, on change of issue state in source project

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

## Summary

We have two projects:

- `Developer` Project
- `Support` Project

When customer raises an issue, the issue is raised in the `Support` Project. This automatically creates an issue in the `Developer` project with the relevant tags.

The issue created in the `Developer` project will have summary `<support-issue-summary>/<support-issue-id>`.

Currently, we are unable to automatically update states in the `Support` project based on change in state in the `Developer` project.
Details are as follows:

### Requirements

Our development team only reviews the `Developer` project. We want to sync changes in states in the `Developer` project to automatically update the relevant issue in the `Support` project.

The `Developer` and `Support` project should have separate states.

#### Implementation

After verifying the guard, and obtaining the relevant target issue ID etc. We use this try catch block to update the target issue state:

```js
    // this version is working
    try {
      // If the current state of the linked issue is 'UAT-QAClosed', make it 'Pending Release'
      if(issue.fields.State.name === "UAT-QAClosed") {
        console.log("start to update the field...")
        targetIssue.fields.State = ctx.HelpDesk_State["InProgress"];
        }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
      console.log("Damn, this means there is an error...");
    }
```

Requirements block, for reference:

```js
  requirements: {
    StateState: {
      name: "State",
      type: entities.State.fieldType,
      UATQAClosed: {name: "UAT-QAClosed"},
      "Pending Release": {name: "Pending Release"},
      InProgress: {name: "In Progress"},
      "SIT-Closed": { name: "SIT-Closed" } // New mapping
    },
   
   HelpDesk_State: {
      name: "State",
      type: entities.State.fieldType,
      UATQAClosed: {name: "UAT-QAClosed"},
      "Pending Release": {name: "Pending Release"},
      InProgress: {name: "In Progress"},
      "SIT-Closed": { name: "SIT-Closed" } // New mapping
    },
    
    project_0: {
      type: entities.Project,
      name: 'Test Project 14 Mar'
    }
}
```

#### Success -- If share same State Field

The target issue is updated successfully if both the `Developer` and `Support` project [shares the same state fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFqlH.png)

See [here for reference!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPeWu.png)

#### Issue -- require assistance

However, when the fields are independent -- the [try-catch block throws an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88zme.png).

However, the [error is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C19pK.png)

#### Workaround

Currently, the workaround is to have both the `Developer` and `Support` project to use the exact same states.
However, this is not a feasible option for us -- and we'd like to check in on any ways we can improve this?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite! 


Will note down the comment on posting code as images -- just double checked, fortunately, I included them in text as well

But going forward, will make note!